# ElasticSearch/ElasticCloud - Connection refused

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the hosted solution from ElasticSearch but I can't seem to connect to the endpoint.

All I keep getting is the following:

```
Failed to connect to xxx port 9243: Connection refused
```

Here's my code...

```
class ElasticSearchApi {

    protected $endpoint;
    protected $auth;
    protected $curl;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->endpoint = 'https://myendpoint.com:9243';
        $this->auth = 'elastic:pass';

    }

    public function getIndices() {

        $this->curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->endpoint);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($this->auth)));
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $responseData = curl_exec($this->curl);
        if(curl_errno($this->curl)) {
            return curl_error($this->curl);
        }
        curl_close($this->curl);

        return $responseData;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following cURL options first:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Connection refused is interesting. If you are using the details with curl on the shell it's working?

Also is there a specific reason why you are not using the official [PHP client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php)? It will make your life much easier around  retries, reestablishing connections,...